# pandas find row+col names for elements with condition

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a pandas dataframe of correlations. I'm searching through the dataframe to find correlations greater than the threshold `0.5` then return the column name and row name (both are strings) for those elements that match the condition.

Currently, I can transform the correlation matrix to values greater than the threshold, then all other values are `NaN` using this:

`correlations[np.abs(correlations) > 0.5]`

Now that I have this matrix of numbers that match my query and `NaN`s, how do I get the row+col names of each element whose value is not `NaN`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you need [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) of `Series` created by [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html), then [`rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html) for new columns names with [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reset_index.html) for columns from `MultiIndex`:

```
np.random.seed(456) 

correlations = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(5,3), columns=list('ABC'))
print (correlations)
          A         B         C
0  0.248756  0.163067  0.783643
1  0.808523  0.625628  0.604114
2  0.885702  0.759117  0.181105
3  0.150169  0.435679  0.385273
4  0.575710  0.146091  0.686593

s = correlations.stack()
df = s[np.abs(s) > 0.5].rename_axis(('idx','col')).reset_index(name='val')
print (df)
   idx col       val
0    0   C  0.783643
1    1   A  0.808523
2    1   B  0.625628
3    1   C  0.604114
4    2   A  0.885702
5    2   B  0.759117
6    4   A  0.575710
7    4   C  0.686593
```

**Detail**:

```
print (s)
0  A    0.248756
   B    0.163067
   C    0.783643
1  A    0.808523
   B    0.625628
   C    0.604114
2  A    0.885702
   B    0.759117
   C    0.181105
3  A    0.150169
   B    0.435679
   C    0.385273
4  A    0.575710
   B    0.146091
   C    0.686593
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you can using `melt`

```
correlations.where(correlations.abs().gt(0.5)).reset_index().melt('index').dropna()
Out[357]: 
    index variable     value
1       1        A  0.808523
2       2        A  0.885702
4       4        A  0.575710
6       1        B  0.625628
7       2        B  0.759117
10      0        C  0.783643
11      1        C  0.604114
14      4        C  0.686593
```